# PostgreSQL create database with parameter syntax error

Tags: postgresql, syntax

I have the following function for creating a PostgreSQL database with `psycopg`:

```python
def create_database() -> None:
    """A function for creating a PostgreSQL database."""
    
    db_name = ('test_db',)
    sql_1 = """SELECT datname FROM pg_database"""
    sql_2 = """CREATE DATABASE %s"""
    with connect('create') as conn:
        try:
            cur = conn.cursor()
            cur.execute(sql_1)
            databases = cur.fetchall()
            if db_name in databases:
                print(f'Database named {db_name[0]} already exists.')
            else:    
                cur.execute(sql_2, db_name)
                cur.close()
                print('Creating database...')
                conn.commit()
                print('Database created.')
            
        except (Exception, DatabaseError) as error: 
            print(error, '\n-> Could not create database.')
```

It gives the following error:

```
syntax error at or near "$1"
LINE 1: CREATE DATABASE $1
                        ^ 
-> Could not create database.
```

What is the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Modifying relevant lines to

```sql
sql_2 = """CREATE DATABASE {}"""
cur.execute(sql.SQL(sql_2).format(sql.Identifier(db_name)))
```

solves the problem.